# Understanding MySQL password

Tags: mysql, passwords, connection-string

Probably I cant get more dumb, but seriously this is the first time I had to think about it(for the first time the single user app goes multi-user from multiple locations). For what  purpose is a MySQL (or any other database for that matter) password? The password we see in connection strings, as if like this:

```
"SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=tree;UID=root;PASSWORD=branch;Min Pool Size = 0;Max Pool Size=200"
```

Is `branch` a code word for user `root` to access database `tree`? Or is it for `root` to access any MySQL database on a specific machine? Or is it a password for any user to access database `tree`? Or password for any user to access any MySQL database on that machine?

So my questions are basically?

1. Is the password specific for the MySQL, or the database, or the user? Or for that particular user for that particular database on that particular MySQL installation? Or any combination of these?
2. Can we have a password for MySQL itself (if thats not the case with `branch`), can we have a password for the db itself (if thats not the case with `branch`) etc?

Sorry for my ignorance ;)

**Edit:** I can run this query to drop my database:

```
query = "DROP DATABASE tree";
```

with the connection string:

```
"SERVER=localhost;UID=root;PASSWORD=branch;Min Pool Size = 0;Max Pool Size=200"
```

Doesn't that mean password is not per database, but per user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)    Is the password specific for the MySQL, or the database, or the
>   user? Or for that particular user for that particular database on that
>   particular MySQL installation? Or any combination of these?

Let me start from scratch. First time when you install MySQL you are asked to enter Username(say root) and Password(say root). This is for the whole server. 
After you connect to the server with the above username and password, you can create user accounts for different reasons like- User 'abc' with password 'xxx' should connect to only one database, say Test. And, another user 'xyz' with password 'aaa' can connect to the server and access all the databases but with only SELECT privilege.

```
 CREATE USER 'abc'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxx'; 
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES; 
 GRANT ALL ON `test`.* TO 'abc'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Here user 'abc' with password 'xxx' can connect to the server but with minimal privileges- By only accessing Test database.

```
 CREATE USER 'xyz'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'aaa'; 
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES; 
 GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'xyz'@'%' ;
```

This user- 'xyz' with password 'aaa' connects to server with only SELECT privilege.

So, three users with different passwords can actually connect to the server with 'root' user with password 'root' has all the privileges whereas 'abc' and 'xyz' has minimal privileges.

I think I have answered your 2nd question also :-)

Comment: terrific job, I understood it as u meant. But I got a q now. So with respect to the connection string I provided, it all depends on the privilege of the user right? I mean user `root` in my connection string can access any database, or just the database specified in connection string, etc depending on how privileged the user is right?

Comment: Exactly. Depending on how privileged the user is MySQL connects to it and shows or works. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html might clear all your doubts.

Comment: Thanks ashwin, lemme wait a few more hours if I could see a couple of more answers..

Answer (score 1):

the password allows the user to connect to the database.

one of each.

i.e. that particular user can connect to that particular instance of the database with that particular password.

Comment: oh..so u mean if more users have to access the database, then they all have to be added to the users table? Or is it typical to have just one admin user and password for a MySQL installation?

Comment: sometimes - you could use a common user for all application access, other times, you may choose to have a named user performing the actions.  it really depends on the requirements for the system

Comment: I do not think that's true. Can you see my edit? I can very well drop a database without specifying the db name in connection string. So doesn't that mean password is not per database?

Comment: let's not get confused between 'database' and 'instance'.  you can have many schemas inside on instance.  one user may have privilege to many schemas in one instance.